# Display latitude and longitude lines on GMap.net control

Tags: c#, .net, gmap.net

All is like I said in title: I need to display latitude and longitude lines on my GMap.net control.

Is there the appropriate method to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not a build-in one, as far as I know. One possibility that comes to my mind, use `GMapPolygon` to draw grid lines. This would need to be handled with care as of number of polygons drawn and how to handle the lines density upon different zoom levels.

Comment: I thought about that already, but it's not quite accurate solution as I hope.
Thank you, though.